# Как создать удаленное соединение между двумя приложениями на pyqt?

Tags: pyqt5, чат

Всех приветствую. Изучаю питон и pyqt. Хочу создать приложение для чата между двумя людьми на разных машинах на windows. То есть у меня и друга установлено приложение и чтобы мне подключиться к нему допустим он говорит мне свой IP адрес и я подключаюсь к нему и мы начинаем чат. Как это осуществить? Заранее спасибо.